# Unable to uninstall global packages installed by pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I installed `python3-pip` in my `WSL2` using `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and after installing it I ran the command `pip list` and I saw it already have packages installed.

**Installed packages**

```
attrs==19.3.0
Automat==0.8.0
blinker==1.4
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloud-init==21.2
colorama==0.4.3
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.8
dbus-python==1.2.16
distro==1.4.0
distro-info===0.23ubuntu1
entrypoints==0.3
httplib2==0.14.0
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
incremental==16.10.1
Jinja2==2.10.1
jsonpatch==1.22
jsonpointer==2.0
jsonschema==3.2.0
keyring==18.0.1
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.2
lazr.uri==1.0.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
more-itertools==4.2.0
netifaces==0.10.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
pexpect==4.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
PyGObject==3.36.0
PyHamcrest==1.9.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyrsistent==0.15.5
pyserial==3.4
python-apt==2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.5
python-debian===0.1.36ubuntu1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.22.0
requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
SecretStorage==2.3.1
service-identity==18.1.0
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.14.0
sos==4.1
ssh-import-id==5.10
systemd-python==234
Twisted==18.9.0
ubuntu-advantage-tools==20.3
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.25.8
wadllib==1.3.3
zipp==1.0.0
zope.interface==4.7.1
```

After searching on Google I found ways to uninstall globally installed packages all at once, after that I ran several commands mentioned below.

**To make a list of all installed packages**

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

**To delete all at once**

`pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y` or `sudo pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y`

after running this command I get an error

```
Found existing installation: attrs 19.3.0
Not uninstalling attrs at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'attrs'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

for every package.

I am using **`WSL2`** with **`Ubuntu=20.04 LTS`** and my default shell is `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh`.

---

Apart that I have 4 versions of python in my `Ubuntu=20.04 LTS`. Do I need to keep all of them??

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: If these packages are in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` (have a look in that directory to see if all these packages are indeed shown there), then it is likely the *system* package manager has installed those, and you should use the system package manager to uninstall them, not pip. For example (guessing somewhat), `sudo apt remove python3-attrs` and the like. To verify, you can run `apt search python3 | grep installed` and see what is listed.

Comment: Also: is there a particular reason you want to uninstall these packages? For example, are you (very) short on disk space?

Comment: @9769953 I am not low on diskspace I just don't want any of package installed in main system. I will install the needed once in the `virtual environment`.

Comment: @9769953 and yes they all are available in `/use/lib/python3/dist-package/`. Also you are saying I need to uninstall all of them one-by-one?? `sudo apt remove python3-attr` and so on.??

Comment: Yes, possibly, you'd have to uninstall them all one by one.

Comment: But if they're not in your way in any way, I'd just leave them where they are. If you are going to work with venv's anyway, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: First, however, make sure you have the correct Python 3 version. Python 3.8 and 3.9 are too close together, that they may cause clashes for you if you don't know what you're doing (e.g., `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` obviously doesn't show any distinction between 3.8 and 3.9, which means you don't know for which Python 3 version you'll have things installed. Same for `pip`: `pip` may be `pip 2.7` (likely not), `pip 3.8` or `pip 3.9`.

Comment: I ran command `python3 -V` it is displaying `3.8.10`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236929/discussion-between-kunal-tanwar-and-9769953).

Comment: What is `which python3.9`? And `which python3.8`? Also, how did you list your Python versions in the picture above?

Comment: I get this list after I cd in `/usr/lib`

Comment: Hmm, that seems iffy, if the operating system has python 3.8 and 3.9 next to each other. Just be careful then to distinguish them. `/usr/lib` is an awkward place for Python executables anyway; they should be in `/usr/bin/` instead. Unless you listed the directories, but I see no indication of that.

Comment: The above doesn't answer your question, they're just comments to point out you may have a bit of an awkward Python installation. But as a I said: I would ignore the installed packages, especially if you are going to use virtual environments anyway, and leave the packages be.

Comment: I think I should do the same!! Thanks for your time so far 